# Google Search console: Blocked due to access forbidden (403) when blocking all country except (India, Srilanka)

Tags: cloudflare, firewall, google-search-console, googlebot, google-index

I am a very old user of cloudflare for the last 4 Years, I have 14+ websites of different categories which has have added to cloudflare last year. My website was accessible and ranked on google which was running very perfectly fine but in the last few days my all website is accessible from all the browsers. Right now, all my websites are running perfectly, But when i go to Google search console and to “Live URL inspection” it shows this error “This page cannot be indexed. Pages that aren’t indexed can’t be served on Google. See the details below to learn why it can’t be indexed Learn more
Failed: Blocked due to access forbidden (403)”

I have activated Cloudflare WAF (Firewall) last year too and the rule is "I am blocking other countries users except india, Srilanka & Nepal " When deactivate firewall my error of google search console gone, but when i again activated the issues comes again. I want to fix this issue… I just want to turn on my firewall and use google search console too, my seo ranking is very low dues to this …please help

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Google just introduced a new user agent for the url inspection tool:

https://www.seroundtable.com/google-adds-google-inspectiontool-to-crawlers-35402.html

I don't think they coordinated with cloudflare.

I re-enabled this on a client site by creating a WAF rule that skipped processing for that user agent:

```
(http.user_agent contains "Google-InspectionTool")
```

BTW, I don't believe the tool being blocked has any effect on indexing. It will, however, make certain folks lose their minds.

I'm sure it'll work itself out in the next few days.

Comment: Hi Robet Moskal,